# Linking .lib file: fatal error LNK1107

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, glut

I am trying to compile a project containing code from 
[this page](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/tpsdemo/).

I added the required glut32.lib to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

```
glut32.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x1E9E

Build FAILED.
```

I've read that it's a common mistake to link to the dll instead of the lib, but here I correctly linked to the .lib

What's the reason for this error?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't corrupt?

Comment: yep, re-downloading solved my prob, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the docs, LNK1107 can mean that either a dll file was erroneously linked OR that the correctly linked .lib file is corrupt (which I suspected to occur rather rarely). Apparently the latter one was the case here as re-downloading the lib solved my issue.